# Why does Perl 6 throw an X::AdHoc exception for my subset type?

Tags: exception, types, raku

*This is a reported bug in Perl 6: [X::AdHoc instead of X::TypeCheck::Binding with subset parameter](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=126763), first reported in November 2015.*

---

While playing with my Perl 6 module [Chemisty::Elements](https://github.com/briandfoy/perl6-chemistry-elements), I've run into an [Exception](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Exception) issue I didn't expect.

I define a type, `ZInt`, which limits numbers to the ordinal numbers found on the periodic chart (which I've faked a bit here). I then use that type to constrain a parameter to a subroutine. I expected to get some sort of [X::TypeCheck](https://docs.perl6.org/type/X$COLON$COLONTypeCheck), but I get [X::AdHoc](https://docs.perl6.org/type/X$COLON$COLONAdHoc) instead:

```
use v6;

subset ZInt of Cool is export where {
    state ( $min, $max ) = <1 120>;
    ( $_.truncate == $_ and $min <= $_ <= $max )
        or warn "Z must be between a positive whole number from $min to $max. Got <$_>."
    };

sub foo ( ZInt $Z ) { say $Z }

try {
    CATCH {
        default { .^name.say }
        }

    foo( 156 );
    }
```

First, I get the warning twice, which is weird:

> Z must be between a positive whole number from 1 to 120. Got <156>.  in block  at zint.p6 line 5
>   Z must be between a positive whole number from 1 to 120. Got <156>.  in block  at zint.p6 line 5
>   X::AdHoc

But, I get the `X::AdHoc` type when I'd rather people knew it was a type error.

I checked what would happen without the `warn` and got `X::AdHoc` again:

```
subset ZInt of Cool is export where {
    state ( $min, $max ) = <1 120>;
    ( $_.truncate == $_ and $min <= $_ <= $max )
    };
```

So, I figured I could throw my own exception:

```
subset ZInt of Cool is export where {
    state ( $min, $max ) = <1 120>;
    ( $_.truncate == $_ and $min <= $_ <= $max )
        or X::TypeCheck.new.throw;
    };
```

But, I get a warning:

> Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context
>   Any of .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can stringify undefined things, if needed.

At this point I don't know what's complaining. I figure one of those methods expects something I'm not supplying but I don't see anything about parameters for `new` or `throw` in the docs.

How do I get the type I want without the warning, along with my custom text?

Comment: I recommend asking it on perl6-users also

Comment: This is an open bug: https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=126763

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't throw the exception or warn with one. Instead, you want to fail:

```
subset ZInt of Cool is export where {
    state ( $min, $max ) = <1 120>;
    ( $_.truncate == $_ and $min <= $_ <= $max )
        or fail "Z must be between a positive whole number from $min to $max. Got <$_>."
};
```

I believe that's your intent. Failing with your own exception is fine too, but X::TypeCheck has a bug in it. It should either require "operation" or provide a reasonable default as it does for "got" and "expected".

```
subset ZInt of Cool is export where {
    state ( $min, $max ) = <1 120>;
    ( $_.truncate == $_ and $min <= $_ <= $max )
    or fail X::TypeCheck.new(
            operation => "type check",
            expected  => ::('ZInt'),
            got       => $_,
        );
};
```

Comment: The difference between `fail` and `warn` is that `warn` is immediately loud, while `fail` only becomes loud when it is encountered by some other code, such as when it is assigned to a variable after being returned by a routine.

Comment: The `fail` is good advice here. I'll have to go find the examples I copied that used `warn`. (I'd add your comment to the answer). I still think that a failure in a subset check should throw some sort of type check error. I'll see about fixing TypeCheck.

Comment: I've seen that advice somewhere too, but couldn't find it in my quick search for it.

Comment: Alas, this ultimately won't work because it shortcuts the other TypeCheck failures that do it right. I think I'll have to live with the `X::AdHoc`.

Answer (score 3):

You could pass `--ll-exception` and try to figure out how exactly you end up with the errors and messages you got, but I'm not sure how helpful that will be.

As to the warning about use of an uninitialzed value: You need to provide a named `operation` argument to `X::TypeCheck.new`; other arguments you may provide are `got` and `expected`, cf [core/Exception.pm](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/3b5ef07/src/core/Exception.pm#L1942).

It is however a Bad Idea to throw from a subset declaration as any smartmatch against that particular type will now explode. A slightly better idea would be to `.fail` the exception, but that still doesn't feel right to me: Not being a member of a subset type is not an exceptional condition.

Alternatively, you could provide a multi candidate that does the dying:

```
subset ZInt of Cool where $_ %% 1 && $_ ~~ 1..120;

proto foo($) {*}
multi foo(ZInt $Z) { say $Z }
multi foo($Z) {
    die X::TypeCheck.new(
        operation => 'foo',
        got => $Z,
        expected => ZInt
    );
}
```

That still has issues if you provide an argument like `"hello"` that fails on numeric conversion as `%%` will throw instead of propagating the failure, which could be considered a defect with the Rakudo core setting.

You can work around that one via things like

```
subset ZInt of Cool where { try $_ %% 1 && $_ ~~ 1..120 }
```

or

```
subset ZInt of Cool where { .Numeric andthen $_ %% 1 && $_ ~~ 1..120 }
```

The whole interaction of argument type checking, subsets or where-clauses, failures and exceptions can be somewhat brittle, so you may want to experiment a bit until you arrive at semantics and behaviour you like.

Another approach would be doing a coercion from `Cool` to `Int` with a separate range check:

```
subset ZInt of Int where 1..120 ;

sub foo(Int(Cool) $Z where ZInt) {
    say $Z.perl;
}
```

In an ideal world, there should be some way to express this with a coercing type constraint like `ZInt(Cool)`.

Comment: providing multi subs for this seems like an awful away to program.

Comment: @briandfoy: it's not a perfect solution; my point stands that subsets should not throw; semantically, coercing types like `ZInt(Cool)` would be the right way to do it; the problem with that is that they are implemented by calling `.ZInt` on the input value, whereas it arguably should additionally look for a coercer on the target type; even if that was possible ,it would not help with your problem as subsets currently cannot have methods as they are mere constraints; I've got an idea about another factoring using where clauses, but I'll have to see if it works...

Comment: @briandfoy: added example code for what I'd like to do in theory (but probably would not in practice)

Comment: @briandfoy: simplified the example